# Parsing response with multiple json objects

Tags: karate

I have an API for which response is not a single JSON object but multiple JSON objects such as-

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}
```

As the response is not a valid JSON, i am seeing an parsing error when accessing API call response in karate reports summary. I am still able to access the response using a print statement as shown in the screenshot(I have redacted the actual call/request from screenshot)

[image]

Is there a way to handle such response or return the response AS-IS instead of the error ?

Comment: `yourResponseText.split("\n").map(row => JSON.parse(row))`?

Comment: Do you control this API? The proper way to return multiple JSON object is to return an array. Then your parse will work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are dealing with [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org).

When parsing to JSON fails, the `responseBytes` variable will always be available. So you can do this:

```
* string data = responseBytes
```

And here is how to convert to a JSON array:

```
* text data = 
"""
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}
"""
* def response = data.split('\n').map(x => karate.fromString(x))
```

Comment: Thanks @https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas

That resolved the issue. However It seems when the response is too large it again errors out without even returning the JSONL.

******************************
When method GET
Required array length 2147483639 + 953 is too large
******************************

Comment: @rc22 maybe you can help by contributing a way to replicate and even a PR ;)